# Azure Data Factory For Each Avoid Array

Tags: json, azure, loops, foreach, azure-data-factory

Im quit new in ADF so here's the challenge from me.

I have a Pipeline that consist a LookUp activity and ForEach and inside this a Copy Activity

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When i run this pipeline the first output of the Lookup activity looks like this

[image]

The output contains 11 different values. From my perspective i only see 11 records that will need to be copied to my Sink which is Azure SQL DB.

The input of the ForEach activity looks like this

[image]

During the running the Pipeline copy 11 times and in my sql database it has now 121 records. This amount is based on 11 rows multiple 11 iteration. This is not the output which i expected.
I only expect 11 rows in my sink table. How can i change this pipeline in order to achieve the expected outcome of only 11 rows?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the source of the copy activity? could you include that in the question?

Comment: Hi @Aswin the source of the copy activty is based on OData connection. You can see the configuration on the second image of this post

Comment: I think second image that you shared is lookup activity configuration. If it is not lookup activity configuration, can you add that picture?

Comment: Are you using same config in lookup and copy data source?

Comment: yes indeed @Aswin

Comment: Could you explain your requirement? Because In order to copy data from OData connection, you can use only copy data activity. Why do you use lookup and foreach? Kindly explain the necessity for this.

Comment: Do you want to copy every record sequentially using lookup and foreach? Is that your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to copy data, Lookup activity and copy data source activity should not be given same configuration. If given so, duplicate rows will be copied.
I tried to repro the same in my environment.

[image]

If 3 records are there in source data, 3 times 3 records will be copied.

[image]

[image]

- In order to avoid duplicates, we can use only copy activity to copy data from Source to sink.

[image]

- Only 3 records are in target table.

[image]